# RT notifications via Jabber

Tags: xmpp, request-tracker

Just checknig out if any one's RT setup is sending RT notifications via Jabber to either users or to conference rooms.

This is a pretty useful feature to have, but could not find any reference in the net.

Thanks and regards,

raj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're not right now, but it should be reasonably easy to cobble together using Perl's Net::XMPP module (http://search.cpan.org/~hacker/Net-XMPP-1.02/lib/Net/XMPP.pm).  The page at http://wiki.bestpractical.com/view/Contributions links to lots of example scrips that demonstrate how you can make perl code fire on RT transactions (ticket creations, comments, etc).